# How Do You Launch IIS Express From the Command Line Looking at ProgramFiles (x86)?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, iis-express

That's basically the question. I've tried a couple options:

```
iisexpress /path:"C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\PathToMyApp" /port:9000
iisexpress "/path:C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\PathToMyApp" /port:9000
iisexpress /path:C:\ProgramFiles^ ^(x86^)\PathToMyApp /port:9000
iisexpress "/path:C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\PathToMyApp" /port:9000
iisexpress /path:C:\ProgramFiles%20(x86)\PathToMyApp /port:9000
```

and probably some others that I'm just forgetting. Generally, the command just exits without saying anything. With some of the options, I get:

```
The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:38
+ .\iisexpress /path:%ProgramFiles (x86 <<<< )%\PathToMyApp /port:9000
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this but did you try putting a space between Program and Files?

```
iisexpress /path:"C:\Program Files (x86)\PathToMyApp" /port:9000
```

Comment: Palm, face. Thank you, hysh_00.

Answer (score 2):

Hysh_00 most likely hit the nail on the head with the space in Program Files but i think some languages remove the space.

In PowerShell 3.0 you could use the [stop-parsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) symbol for commands like this to stop PowerShell from interpeting your command line.

```
iisexpress --% /path:"C:\Program Files (x86)\PathToMyApp" /port:9000
```